# LINQ to SQL in c# and database access

Tags: c#, database, linq-to-sql

I do not know how to ask this question. So I will just give an example.

Code:

```
var db = new dbContext();
var dlo = new DataLoadOptions()

dlo.LoadWith<Order>(x => x.Company);
db.LoadOptions = dlo;
var compIds = prms.companies.Select(x => x.Id).ToArray();
```

as I understand with above code I load Company from Order table and then getting companies by their ID's. Is it same as

```
var compIds = (from it in context.GetTable<Order>()
                       select it.Company.Id).ToArray();
```

? Or am I totally confusing two different concepts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are confused about three things:

1. `context.GetTable<Order>()` is the same as `context.Orders` (assuming everything is configured correctly.
2. The queries you've provided as examples are not equivalent; they ask two different questions.  The first is asking "Give me all the Company IDs".  The `DataLoadOptions` won't even be used.  The second is asking Give me every Order's Company ID.  You will get duplicates.
3. `DataLoadOptions` is generally used for eager loading of related object instances, not joining.

I think what you are really looking for is:

```
var uniqueCompanyIDsThatHaveAtLeastOneOrder = db.Orders.Select(o => o.Company.Id).Distinct();
```

Comment: oh yes you are right with `dlo` not being used. I should have wrote `var compIds = db.companies...` Thanks for comment. What I was trying to get at was answered by your 1st point.